# After-bracha on <kezayis of motzi, plus other food

Tags: blessing, shiurim-measurements, bentching, hamotzi-beracha

If someone ate some motzi with other food as a snack (let's say half a filled pita pocket), what, if any, after-bracha should he make?

Assume he ate a kezayis of the other food in 4 minutes, but not a kezayis of bread.

CONSIDERATIONS:

- I was told by someone that [at least] in the Shabbos meal, you can fulfill your obligation to eat a shiur of bread using other food in the meal. But I'm not sure if this would bear on the obligation to bentch, too.
- I read in one source that one doesn't make any after-brocha if one eats less than a kezayis of bread. However, it says [here](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/4105/kzayis-a-guide-to-halachic-food-measurements/#5) that

> if one eats a k’zayis of any other food *{i.e., than bread}* a brocha acharona must be
>   recited.5

Does this imply we should then make the after-brocha--for example, *borei nefashos*--on the other food?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59415/759

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26438/759

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66660/759

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you need to eat a kezayis of the ikar to make a bracha acharona necessitated by the ikar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66660/do-you-need-to-eat-a-kezayis-of-the-ikar-to-make-a-bracha-acharona-necessitated)

Comment: Agree with DoubleAA's proposed dupe. There is an answer there that specifically addresses eating less than *kezayit* bread. Although, I thought 1/2 a pita would be > kezayit. BTW, even though it seems that few people follow this rule, technically, the Torah requirement for *Birkat Hamazon* is *sve'ut* (being "full"). So, if you've filled up on the other items, I don't think there would be any problem saying *birkat hamazon*.

Comment: @DoubleAA This discussed seudah. That discusses ikar v’tafel. Why is it a dupe?

Comment: @DanF IIRC, fish + bread is a particularly weird combination, not sure if the answer there would be relevant more generally.

Comment: @DanF Yeah in that case I think the bread doesn't get a fore-blessing at all, or maybe a shehakol. In my case it gets a motzi (although I'm not positive we bentch on the washing). In short, it's a different case

Comment: @SAH AFAIK, most people automatically assume that any bread eaten during the meal requires washing and hamotzi, and it's the "coverall" bracha. But, in reading the linked question, that's not always the case. Perhaps, many (including myself, until, now) don't know the rules?

Comment: @DanF I'm sure you do know the rules! As for me, the more I learn about brachos, the less I know ;)

Comment: @SAH You're not alone. But, I'm convinced that it's not the halachot of brachot that are complicated. Technology has made them seem complicated. The past few decades has produced various foods that have cropped up in the kosher market that were not around 20 - 30 years ago. Sushi, for example, became popular in the past 20 - 25 years. There's no consensus on what bracha to make on it.

Comment: @DanF Ah but raw barley existed and so did esrog and wine brandy and cornbread...

Comment: @SAH "raw barley" - You've alluded to one of the more complex areas of food brachot that I know of - how is raw produce eaten in your specific area? E.g. if you eat raw chillies, you'd say *shehakol*, but if an Indian eats them, he says *Adama*, b/c it's common for them to eat raw chillies. I have yet to get a definitive answer on the bracha for eating wedge of raw cabbage.

Comment: I learned recently-from this year's manual of hilchos Shavuos, from the Beis Din Tzedek of Crown Heights-that one is obligated in Al Hamichya if he ate one-sixth of a kezayis of mezonos with the other food. I am unsure of whether he would need to make a Borei Nefashos (or other) too; I think not. I also don't know if he has to make Al Hamichya on this 1/6-kezayis if he didn't make mezonos on the food before (if, for one of several reasons, the mezonos did not reach its usual status of ikar.) If he made hamotzi, presumably not. I think it is "no" in other cases too but am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In Hazon Ovedia Brachut maran said that:
if someone eat's less than k’zayis he need's to bless **first and last** bless on other food.
(but not on spread's (ממרחים/סלטים/לפתן) - because of ikar ve-tafel (עיקר וטפל))

the k’zayis time can be up to 7.5 minutes.

i will refer you to this:
http://halachayomit.co.il/he/ReadHalacha.aspx?halachaid=536